# variadic function and parametised safe queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Using node-pg and Postgres 11.

I have a variadic function in postgres

```
CALL schema.function(('1'),('2'))
```

In order to prevent sql injection I need to do something like

```
await client.query('CALL schema.function($1::smallint);', XXX);
```

Where XXX is what the call uses for substitutions.

The problem is that my function expects a list of records, not an array ('1'),('2').

Has anyone else encountered this?

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_events_variadic(
    VARIADIC _events_array event_array[]
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
EVENT_RECORD RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR EVENT_RECORD IN 
    SELECT
        metadata,
        payload
    FROM unnest(_events_array) as t(
        metadata,
        payload
    )
LOOP
INSERT INTO events
    (
        metadata,
        payload
    )
VALUES
    (
        EVENT_RECORD.metadata,
        EVENT_RECORD.payload
    );

END LOOP;

END;
$$;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to safely call a variadic function from nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74438129/how-to-safely-call-a-variadic-function-from-nodejs)

Comment: Hi

It doesn't because I need to pass a list of records into the call function.

Comment: Can you include an example so the difference is somewhat clearer?

Comment: Hi. I am unsure how. The difference is that in the other question it is to do with an array, however the implementation of the SP requires a list of records and in that format. I'm just trying to get the data in safely without using something like a string literal.

Comment: Can't you just change the procedure to take an array?

Comment: Hi jjanes. I thought I did that by stating that the type of _events_array was of a custom type event_array[] :: VARIADIC _events_array event_array[]. Or am I missing something.

Comment: That would also require an array of arrays right?

Comment: @user973347 But what happens if you use the solution from the other answer? `[JSON.stringify(arr)]` Does it give you an error? If so, it would be useful to have that in the question.

Comment: The error was {
    "length": 313,
    "name": "error",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42883",
    "hint": "No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.",
    "position": "6",
    "file": "parse_func.c",
    "line": "605",
    "routine": "ParseFuncOrColumn"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only type of call you expect, `variadic` is just syntax noise. You can redefine your procedure to accept a regular array of type that fits into table `events`, that you're trying to insert into. Also, you don't have to loop over a select from `unnest()` - there's a [`FORACH`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) loop that lets you iterate over the array directly.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_events ( events_array events[] )
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    event_record events;
BEGIN
FOREACH event_record IN ARRAY events_array LOOP
    INSERT INTO events
    (   metadata,
        payload
    )
    VALUES
    (   event_record.metadata,
        event_record.payload
    );
END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

You can also insert directly from a select without any loop, gaining some performance from that and from switching to plain `language SQL` that doesn't have the PLpgSQL overhead:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_events ( events_array events[] )
LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
INSERT INTO events
(   metadata,
    payload
)
select 
    event_record.metadata, 
    event_record.payload
from unnest(events_array) 
  as event_record
    (   metadata,
        payload
    )
$$;
```

You can either cast each element in the array, or cast the whole array at once:

```javascript
await client.query('CALL schema.function( ARRAY[$1]::events[] );', XXX);
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/cTBcgJ98) If you happen to initially get a `malformed record literal` error after these changes, it means that some or all of what you're supplying as `XXX` isn't a valid set of values that can make up `events` record. [Another demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NGK74PWi), showing some examples.

I'm naively assuming your `events` table has only those two columns - if it has more, you'll have to define an intermediate type or table and use that as your array type in procedure definition and call argument cast. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/hs0TrEvf)

In this case [`variadic`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) would be useful if you wanted to be able to use both types of calls below:

```sql
call update_events( --not an array in a strict sense, just a bunch of arguments
     ('metadata1','payload1')::events,
     ('metadata2','payload2')::events,
     ('metadata3','payload3')::events);
```

The above isn't passing an array in a strict sense, just a bunch of arguments that the function will internally collect and make available as a single, actual array.

```sql
call update_events( VARIADIC
     ARRAY[('metadata1','payload1'),
           ('metadata2','payload2'),
           ('metadata3','payload3')
          ]::events[] );
```

`VARIADIC` informs the function that nothing has to be collected into an array as the argument list is already provided as one.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you Zegarek

Comment: "*I'm naively assuming your `events` table has only those two columns*" - assuming there's no identity columns or anything else that needs to be ignored by the insert, this seems like a practical use case to simplify to `INSERT INTO events SELECT * FROM UNNEST(events_array);`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, and that's exactly what the second procedure example is simplified to, making the whole thing basically an alias. Still, I would guess the OP or anyone new ending up here, might actually be doing something more in a procedure like that and we're shown only the part that was causing trouble.